# Logical Query to calculate weeks

Tags: php, logic, weblogic, week-number

I ask user to enter start and end date in a certain application. Then I calculate the no. of weeks in between these two dates.

I want to fetch documents created per week in the given period of time.
I am unable to implement a logic which will help me to fetch first week, second week, third week, and so on.

I will use this as input to database and then create graph. I am using php as the server side language. Anyone could suggest me the Algorithm.

**ex:**

```
Start date: 20/07/2012

End Date: 19/02/2013.

Total no. of days: 214.

Total no. of weeks: 30 (30 weeks and 4 days)
```

I want to fetch period of 20/07/2012 to 27/07/2012 and no. of Docs during this period. Till 15/02/2013.

Comment: use aggregate function like count() and group by year AND week of year https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database structure here is a sample of what you require

```
SELECT YEAR(doc_created) AS report_year, WEEKOFYEAR(doc_created) AS report_week, COUNT(*) AS doc_count
FROM documents
WHERE doc_created BETWEEN '2012-07-20' AND '2013-07-19'
GROUP BY YEAR(doc_created), WEEKOFYEAR(doc_created)
```

grouping by weekofyear is not enough, as period may overlap the next year, so we should also include the year.

```
possible results:  
year  week  docs  
2012  1     4  
2012  3     1  
2013  1     65  
2013  2     4
```

as you can see 2012 week 1 would overlap 2013 week 1, if we just used week number.

for your grid/graph use the reference (year wk) and amount (docs)
e.g. 2012wk1 is 4, 2012wk3 is 1

Comment: I have handled the database element, I need algorithm to implement these details in graphical image, which i have created. For now I am just able to print No. of docs selected on single day.

Comment: The above query will give `report_year, report_week, doc_count` __for each week__, so no algorithm is required, you just plug the numbers into your grid or image. (check out http://phpchart.net/)

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this code:



     $start_date    =   "20-07-2012";
    $end_date   =   "20-08-2012 ";

    while($start_date){
        if(strtotime($start_date) > strtotime($end_date)){
            exit;
        }
        $start_date =   strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($start_date));
        $start_date =   date("d-m-Y", $start_date);
        echo $start_date;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: strtotime() will not work correctly on UK dates. It will assume it is US if possible. so 01-03-2012 will give 3rd Jan not 1st March.

Comment: Using exit to stop a while loop? are you serious?!